# Adding associated data in model::beforeSave

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to add associated data to during cakePHPs beforeSave() but it looks like cakePHP is ignoring it.

```
<?php
App::uses("AppModel", "Model");

class Recipe extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array('Ingredient');

    public function beforeSave($options=array()) {
        if(!isset($this->data["Ingredient"])) {
            Debugger::log("data[Ingredient] didn't exist! adding some ingredients...");
            $this->data["Ingredient"] = array(
                array(
                    'Ingredient' => array(
                        'name' => 'Gluten Free Flour',
                        'amount' => '12 cups'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'Ingredient' => array(
                        'name' => 'Sugar',
                        'amount' => '50 cups'
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'Ingredient' => array(
                        'name' => 'A shoe',
                        'amount' => 'Just one'
                    )
                ),
            );
        }
        Debugger::log("Saving Data: ");
        Debugger::log($this->data, 7, 10);

        return true;
    }
}
```

In my `RecipesController` I have this:

```
public function test_save() {
    //Test saving With the ingredients in the recipe
    Debugger::log("Saving w/ ingredients");
    Debugger::log($this->Recipe->saveAssociated(array(
        'Recipe' => array(
            'name' => 'Test Recipe 1'
        ),  
        'Ingredient' => array(
            array(
                'name' => 'Test Ingredient 1 for Test Recipe 1',
                'amount' => 'a few'
            ),  
            array(
                'name' => 'Test Ingredient 2 for Test Recipe 1',
                'amount' => 'a lot'
            )   
        )   
    )));

    Debugger::log("Saving w/o ingredients");
    Debugger::log($this->Recipe->saveAssociated(array(
        'Recipe' => array(
            'name' => 'Test Recipe 2'
        )   
    )));
}
```

The save with ingredients works, but the save without ingredients doesn't, the data in Recipe->data before `beforeSave` returns is this:

```
array(
    'Recipe' => array(
        'name' => 'Test Recipe 1'
    ),
    'Ingredient' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Ingredient' => array(
                'name' => 'Test Ingredient 1 for Test Recipe 1',
                'amount' => 'a few'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Ingredient' => array(
                'name' => 'Test Ingredient 2 for Test Recipe 1',
                'amount' => 'a lot'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

And when Ingredient is  added in the before save:

```
array(
    'Recipe' => array(
        'name' => 'Test Recipe 1'
    ),
    'Ingredient' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Ingredient' => array(
                'name' => 'Gluten Free Flour',
                'amount' => '12 cups'
            )
        ),
        (int) 1 => array(
            'Ingredient' => array(
                'name' => 'Sugar',
                'amount' => '50 cups'
            )
        ),
        (int) 2 => array(
            'Ingredient' => array(
                'name' => 'A shoe',
                'amount' => 'Just one'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

When the data is in the array before I call a save method, it'll work just fine, only when I try and add the associated data in the beforeSave.

Comment: Are you sure that it's only ignoring the Ingredient data, and not just not saving anything at all? To me it looks like that this is what would happen using that code.

Comment: Can you write the save function you are using in the controller. like saveAssociated;

Comment: I've updated the question to include the save method I'm using, and also what the models data looks like before leaving the beforeSave callback

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> Be sure that beforeSave() returns true, or your save is going to fail.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave

---

**Edited:** I tested your code and you are right, related data added in `beforeSave()` is being ignored. This is happening because you cannot add or modify related data in a model's `beforeSave()`. It means that, in your Recipe's `beforeSave()`, you cannot neither add Ingredients  nor modify the Ingredients you previously attached to Recipe in your controller.

In your Recipe's `beforeSave()` you can only modify Recipe data.

Is this a bug? It is not, according to Mark Story (creator of CakePHP):

> Its a feature, as currently saveAll **only lets you use beforeSave to
>   modify the record that's about to be saved, not the full data set**. I
>   personally don't feel that should change, but its something that could
>   be discussed.

This statement is about `saveAll()` but the important part is what he said about `beforeSave()`. Check the full thread: https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/1765

Comment: I guess this is what I get for trying to pull out the relevant bits of code :P. the `beforeSave` method IS returning true, I just forgot to put that in my example, I'll create a testing cake app to create a working example, and update the question with that

Comment: I've updated the question to have a proper beforeSave

Comment: Tested your code and it blew my mind. You were right, but there is an explanation. Edited my answer with some info I found.